# Access Google user content programmatically using OAuth

Tags: android, oauth, google-oauth, google-account

[image: Devices attached to my Google account]

So these are the devices attached to my Google account. As every one knows, Google secures information provided by you, which includes, personal info, apps registered, devices connected etc..  You can access the info of a logged in user in your browser from [Google account info](https://myaccount.google.com/)

**Question 1:** What are all the possible info I can get, willingly from the end user AKA using OAuth. [Google OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/) does not tell about it properly.

**Question 2:** If OAuth is not the correct way to get a Google user content, then by other means I can get the info, especially I am interested in Devices registered.

Thanks for Reading... Need your help to build an Android App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that information is only available to administrators of Google Apps domains (and to accounts that have delegated administration access) and then they can only retrieve that info for the users in their Google Apps domain. See: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-mobile-devices and https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the info. Looks like I have to create my own service to get  devices, linked with the user account.